# Excel Macro Combo Box List, Passing value from a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with passing a Value into a list from Cells.
The code works and populates the dropdown list when I manually put in the array Values:

```
ddlBOV.List = Array("1", "2", "3")
```

This will show 3 dropdown items

> 1
>   2
>   3

But if I try to use the values from a worksheet cell it will show the entire cell value:

```
ddlBOV.List = Array(MyWorksheet.Cells(5, 2).Value)
```

It will show a single dropdown item

> "1", "2", "3"

I have tried with the cell formatted as General and Text both gave the same values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code:

`ddlBOV.List = Split(MyWorksheet.Cells(5, 2).Value),",")`

This uses the awesome `Split` function to turn a delimited string into an array.